# Symfony 3 en linux

Tags: linux, xampp, symfony3

[image]

Soy novato en synfony y acabo de instalar y me ocurre este error ¿A alguien más le ha pasado esto? ¿Como lo soluciono?

Answer (score 0):

En la raiz del proyecto hacer lo siguiente:

1. mkdir var/cache var/logs
2. setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx var/cache var/logs
3. setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx var/cache var/logs
4. php bin/console cache:clear

lo que hace es habilitar permisos de esritura a la cache

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolvi insertando el comando en la carpeta de mi proyecto

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 var/
```

Comment: y sabes que hace ese comando?

Comment: No es lo correcto ya que con eso estas vando todos lo permisos a tu carpeta y cualquier usuario podria manipularla, lo ideal es usa los SETFACL